# Zend_Auth fails to write to storage

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth

I have yet another weird annoying thing going on with Zend.

Basically, I have the following code after creating a user domain:

```
$this->auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$this->view->user = $this->user = $this->auth->getIdentity();
$this->user->idSite = $idSite;
$this->user->urlSite = $urlSite;
$this->auth->getStorage()->write($this->user);
```

What FURIOUSLY annoys me is that the auth->getIdentity() just moments after that:

```
[idSite] => 0
[urlSite] =>
```

So from here it gets worse: If I REFRESH or if any of the other parameters of the form fail and send me to the SAME FORM, but WITHOUT TOUCHING THE ABOVE SCRIPT, the auth-getIdentity() correctly returns:

```
[idSite] => 2431
[urlSite] => exampledomain
```

Which means that the code is correct and working, BUT if the form is filled out correctly and everything adds up nicely, I redirect to the next step: $this->_redirect('nextstep'), and neither idSite or urlSite remain empty forever.

Why is this? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had the same issue and I think it is better to go via the route of using the session namespace functionality:

```
$oSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('myStorage');
$oSession->foo = "bar";
$oSession->baz = 123;
```

And you can recover the data by:

```
$oSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('myStorage');
$this->view->foo = $oSession->foo;
```

There are some more clues here: [Zend_Auth](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/zend.auth.html#zend.auth.introduction.persistence) the main message of which is that the storage of Zend_Auth data is actually just a namespace.

The default access to this would be similar to :

`$oSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Zend_Auth')`;

Comment: This is one year later and I'm constructing a different project. The same problems have led me down the same path and i have found your post again. This is THE solution. It solves everything, always works and it clean and pure in its implementation, especially when abstracted.

Answer (score 1):

I also had trouble with Zend_Auth not writing to storage. However, after seeing the answer by Ian Lewis and your response I realised it was probably writing ok, but not reading. I had previously changed the 'name' setting in my session to my own namespace. Once I removed this and started using the default again my Zend_Auth worked fine.